# Not able to retrieve Plist value to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I use following code to display the plist into NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary ,but when i print that variable it returns null value? please help me?

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *Path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Recent.plist"];
NSLog(@"%@",Path); //Path is correct

NSDictionary *d=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:Path];
NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:Path];
NSLog(@"%@",d);
```

Comment: Are you sure it's root is dictionary and not array? Please show how you are creating it in that documents directory.

Comment: Path is correct as you told but have you check `BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:Path];` or not ?
`

Comment: Show the text at the start of the file too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddy ,Your code is correct ,but please make sure that your plist root is array or dictionary

i think it should be array in your case

please try this code ,i just change that NSMutableDictionary to NSMutableArray in your code

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *Path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Recent.plist"];
NSLog(@"%@",Path);


NSMutableArray *d = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:Path];
```

It has to work